# How to customize the Do Not Disturb feature for weekends?

Tags: ios, iphone, do-not-disturb

I have the Do Not Disturb feature scheduled to work from Midnight to 7 am.  This works great.

However, on the weekend I like to sleep in and would like the Do Not Disturb feature to go until 9 am.  But I do not see this feature.  It's like all or nothing.

Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This currently can't be done.** Schedules you select apply to all the days of the week.

You can provide feedback to Apple on the following page:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html

Answer (score 5):

It now can be done!
Use the automation section of the Shortcuts app. [image: Screenshot]