# Can I schedule Do Not Disturb for specific days?

Tags: iphone, ios, do-not-disturb

I currently have Do Not Disturb on my iPhone (iOS 9) scheduled to run while I am at college. The only issue is that I am not at college every day.

Is there a way I can schedule Do Not Disturb for certain days? (For example: Tuesday-Thursday)

Comment: I think what you are asking is not possible. Maybe an App can be designed to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sadly, on a non jailbroken phone you can only set Do Not Disturb to set hours, regardless of which day.  Therefore, every day gets the same hours.

What would be nice, would be a system like the alarms where you can set multiple ones and have them repeat on choosable days, then you could set 2 DND period, one to cover weekdays, and one for weekends etc.

I would recommend making a feature request at [this link.](http://www.apple.com/feedback/)

Comment: Oh well. Thanks for your answer. This is what I was expecting. Unfortunately I do not want to jailbreak my device since I find there is no need to on iOS 9 and all it does is make my phone unstable, also when I want to update when jailbroken I would need to restore first.

Comment: it's such a common use case what a shame

Comment: To add to your "would be nice" -- they since then added Automation which can be used: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/398408/326908

Answer (score -1):

The only way to achieve that is with a jailbreak.

Comment: Please specify how this can be accomplished with a jailbroken iPhone.

Comment: How ? Well would say via one of the many third party apps that are not on the Apple site . Would be surprised if something was not there for this.